# How could I preview the final result when applying kustomizations to a git repo with helm templates?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kustomize, fluxcd

I have a git repo with helm charts, and a git repo per environment with kustomizations for those charts. All of this in working great with flux. But I don't know how to "preview" my changes to the kustomization files.

Let's say I edit the dev environment kustomization, can I preview what the final yaml file will look like ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a look at 2 different commands:

- [flux diff](https://fluxcd.io/flux/cmd/flux_diff_kustomization/) - "The diff command does a build, then it performs a server-side dry-run and prints the diff."
- [kustomize build](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/cmd/build/) - "It recursively builds (aka hydrates) the `kustomization.yaml` you point it to, resulting in a set of Kubernetes resources ready to be deployed."

As Flux `Kustomization` only points to a standard kustomize file, you can use the kustomize build to see the manifests.

PS: For helm, check out [helm template](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_template/)